How to connect Lua module with Simion workbench program
​
Hi,
I am a new user of Simion and Lua, so probably my question is rather silly, but I will be very grateful for the answer though)
I would like to realize some useful Simion functions as separate Lua modules, that will be required from Simion workbench program.
Say, I have the following Lua module test.lua


test = {}

function test.print_ion_number()
  print("ion number = ", ion_number)
end

return test



And I want to use it in segment.other_actions() function of Simion workbench program as


test = require "test"

simion.workbench_program()
function segment.other_actions()
  test.print_ion_number()
end



But what I get is nil, since my function from test module doesn't see Simion ion_number variable.
So, my question is: how make Simion segment variables visible for external modules? I understand that it is probably possible to pass all of them to it as a table, but maybe there is more convenient way to do it?
Thank you
​
